# XGBoostClassifier: model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type="gain") not return entire feature importance

Tags: python, xgboost

After training xgboost classification model on numeraical dataset, I use `model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type="gain")` to show feature importance. The output does not include all features:

> {'f0': 184.0655517578125, 'f6': 101.228271484375, 'f7': 82.6279296875,
> 'f9': 169.0750732421875, 'f10': 54.0909423828125, 'f12':
> 104.12409973144531, 'f16': 79.05672454833984, 'f18': 81.51226806640625, 'f19': 39.9144287109375, 'f21': 142.88848876953125, 'f22': 237.5372314453125, 'f25': 32.79817581176758, 'f27':
> 219.1912841796875, 'f31': 154.21551513671875, 'f32': 34.7470703125}

The training dataset has 34 columns. Why did `.get_score(importance_type="gain")` not calculate all feature importances?

python version: `3.9`
xgboost version: `1.6.2`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say definitively from the information provided, but I'd say that the model is only splitting on a subset of all the columns in your dataset.

The [xgboost API reference](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html) states that `get_score()` with `importance_type='gain'` returns

> the average gain across all splits the feature is used in.

If the underlying xgboost model does not split across all the variables then it won't return scores for those variables. This could occur if you only used a few estimators or the variables are really not related to the target at all.